# show / Hide Checkbox in apex5.0

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created a PI, :P1_ID defined as checkbox and added a DA to update a field on specific criteria. 
On form, have a :P1_REF_NAME which contain the emailAdd of user who has login 
e.g app_user = TESTUSER
:P1_REF_NAME = TESTUSER@TESTING.COM

I want to do something like that the checkbox option should be hidden / disable when User who login access his own record.

Any idea, How is it possible to do that pls?

Answer (score 1):

If P1_REF_NAME contains the username then you could put a Condition on the item of type PL/SQL with expression

```
:P1_REF_NAME != :APP_USER
```

Then the item will not be rendered for the user's own record.

However, in your case it seems that the item contains a different value, i.e. the email address associated with the user.  Presumably this is held in some table.  In that case you can use a condition of type "SQL Not Exists" with an expression something like:

```
select null
  from my_user_table
 where username = :APP_USER
   and email_address = :P1_REF_NAME
```

Comment: thanks! how to modify the condition for the Chkbx when the :P1_REF_NAME = TESTUSER@TESTING.COM and app_user TEST ?